How to download and run HA-Proxy Data Plane API on Mac Intel Chip
I am a frontend end developer. I was trying to run backend locally to test services of frontend. To run backend we need to have HA-Proxy and HAProxy Data Plane API.
So, I downloaded HA-Proxy via Home-brew on MacBook Pro Intel Chip using:
~% brew install haproxy

After that to verify the version, I used:
~% haproxy -version                                       
HAProxy version 3.1.0-f2b9791 2024/11/26 - https://haproxy.org/
Status: stable branch - will stop receiving fixes around Q1 2026.
Known bugs: http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-3.1.0.html
Running on: Darwin 22.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Wed Jul 31 21:42:48 PDT 2024; root:xnu-8796.141.3.707.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Which shows HA-Proxy is installed successfully; to find out the path I used:
~% which haproxy
/usr/local/bin/haproxy

Now it was time to download HA-Proxy Data Plane API, so I head towards
https://github.com/haproxytech/dataplaneapi/releases/
and downloaded

dataplaneapi_3.0.3_darwin_x86_64.tar.gz

After unzipping it using:
tar -xvzf dataplaneapi_3.0.3_darwin_x86_64.tar.gz

Few Files showed up, dataplaneapi, dataplaneapi.yml.dist, LICENSE, README.md, CHANGELOG.md
So according to steps mentioned in "https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/haproxy-data-plane-api/installation/install-on-haproxy/"
chmod +x dataplaneapi

Copy the dataplaneapi program to /usr/local/bin/:
sudo cp dataplaneapi /usr/local/bin/

Copy the Data Plane API configuration file to /etc/haproxy/dataplaneapi.yml:
sudo cp dataplaneapi.yml.dist /etc/haproxy/dataplaneapi.yml 

After that I checked dataplaneAPI version:
~% dataplaneapi --version
2024/11/30 13:17:19 maxprocs: Leaving GOMAXPROCS=8: CPU quota undefined
2024/11/30 13:17:19 INFO GOMEMLIMIT is already set, skipping package=github.com/KimMachineGun/automemlimit/memlimit GOMEMLIMIT=512MiB
HAProxy Data Plane API v3.0.3 f1d4189a

Build from: https://github.com/haproxytech/dataplaneapi
Build date: 2024-10-10T13:42:11Z

Now when I try to run:
sudo dataplaneapi -f /etc/haproxy/dataplaneapi.yml 
2024/11/30 13:23:40 maxprocs: Leaving GOMAXPROCS=8: CPU quota undefined
2024/11/30 13:23:40 ERROR failed to set GOMEMLIMIT package=github.com/KimMachineGun/automemlimit/memlimit error="failed to set GOMEMLIMIT: cgroups is not supported on this system"

What is this error and how to resolve it:

ERROR failed to set GOMEMLIMIT package=github.com/KimMachineGun/automemlimit/memlimit error="failed to set GOMEMLIMIT: cgroups is not supported on this system"

Let just say I ignore this error and continue:
~% sudo curl http://127.0.0.1:5555/v2/services/haproxy/configuration/version                       

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5555 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

Lets track it down from logs:
~% tail -f /var/log/dataplaneapi.log
time="2024-11-30T13:23:41+05:00" level=fatal msg="Error initializing configuration client: error setting up configuration client: failed to find HAProxy: path to HAProxy binary not valid: /usr/sbin/haproxy, err: fork/exec /usr/sbin/haproxy: no such file or directory"

Then I:
sudo nano /usr/local/etc/dataplaneapi.yml

and set the path according to my home brew HAproxy location in HAproxy Section but still the problem persists.
Here is my default dataplaneapi.yml.dist which is not running:
 dataplaneapi:
      host: 0.0.0.0
      port: 5555
      userlist:
        userlist: dataplaneapi
      resources:
        maps_dir: /etc/haproxy/maps
        ssl_certs_dir: /etc/haproxy/ssl
        general_storage_dir: /etc/haproxy/general
        spoe_dir: /etc/haproxy/spoe
      transaction:
        transaction_dir: /var/lib/dataplaneapi/transactions
        backups_number: 10
        backups_dir: /var/lib/dataplaneapi/backups
    haproxy:
      config_file: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
      haproxy_bin: /usr/sbin/haproxy
      reload:
        reload_delay: 5
          service_name: haproxy
        reload_strategy: systemd
    log_targets:
    - log_to: file
      log_file: /var/log/dataplaneapi.log
      log_level: info
      log_types:
      - access
      - app  

This is my new config dataplaneapi.yml.dist

        config_version: 2
    name: 192.168.1.4
    dataplaneapi:
      host: 0.0.0.0
      port: 5555
      advertised:
        api_address: ""
        api_port: 0
      scheme:
      - http
      userlist:
        userlist: dataplaneapi
      transaction:
        transaction_dir: /var/lib/dataplaneapi/transactions
        backups_number: 10
        backups_dir: /var/lib/dataplaneapi/backups
      resources:
        maps_dir: /etc/haproxy/maps
        ssl_certs_dir: /etc/haproxy/ssl
    general_storage_dir: /etc/haproxy/general
    spoe_dir: /etc/haproxy/spoe
    haproxy:
  config_file: /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
  haproxy_bin: /usr/local/bin/haproxy
  reload:
    reload_delay: 5
    service_name: haproxy
    reload_strategy: systemd
    log_targets:
     log_to: file
     log_file: /var/log/dataplaneapi.log
     log_level: info
     log_types:
     - access
     - app  

Please let me know alternative way to install and run HA Proxy Data plane API in a Mac.
